# Android app to tell callers who withhold their number that I won't take their call, and why

Tags: android

I can find apps which will blocks calls from those who withhold their numbers.

What I am looking for is something which, in the background, answers such a call and plays a message, without me hearing or interacting.

I would be happy with a canned message "I do not accept calls from those who withhold their number", but text to speech of a message of my choice, or playing back a message which I record would be "nice to have".

Preferably [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but I would be willing to pay a small amount.

Comment: You can use Tasker to accomplish this. It is not free and there is a steep learnig curve, however it is very useful

Comment: Feel free to post an answer explaining how to use Tasker to do this